# django syncdb script - filesystem location + altering the script?

Tags: django, django-models

i'm using django for a few projects already and now i'm facing a problem with the syncdb command.
I need to alter the functionality of that command, have you got any experience with that?

`python manage.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I haven't found any `execute_from_command_line` on file system (to be more precise, in the location `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management`).

Any ideas, where is executed script located?

2) question:

Have you got any experience with manual altering of django database (PostgreSQL) after `syncdb` is run and not running `syncdb` again to keep the changes?

I need to change django constraints

`ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to

`ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

but if i do it manually, it is overwritten after syncdb is called again.

Comment: I think you're better off in overruling the SQL to create the tables. See the Django FAQ [How do I add database-specific options to my CREATE TABLE statements, such as specifying MyISAM as the table type?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-do-i-add-database-specific-options-to-my-create-table-statements-such-as-specifying-myisam-as-the-table-type) for more on that. Use [`manage.py sql app`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sql) to show the current `CREATE TABLE` SQL being sent. Editing Django core files is not really a nice approach...

Comment: I think syncdb works only once when you have written a new model class for the first time. For any ALTER work you can ue south migration in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks gertvdijk for the right direction.
The solution is to use Custom SQL queries, which are run just after creating the tables.

Django documentation can be found over here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#initial-sql